# Keras input image size

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have set of images of size 200x600(WxH), but when I am displaying it using pyplot, they look like they have size of 600x200.

```py
train_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    data_dir,
    validation_split=0.2,
    subset="training",
    seed=123,
    image_size=(200, 600),
    batch_size=batch_size)
```

I am not sure why it is so. When I change it to **image_size=(600, 200)** it looks ok, but tensorflowjs is complaining about shape.

```
let tensorImg = tf.browser.fromPixels(canvas).resizeNearestNeighbor([200, 600]).toFloat().expandDims();
```

Any hints?

Answer (score 0):

I tested with my own dataset its working as expected.
**Sample code below**

```
batch_size = 32
img_height = 200
img_width = 600

train_ds = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
  data_dir,
  validation_split=0.2,
  subset="training",
  seed=123,
  image_size=(img_height, img_width),
  batch_size=batch_size)

val_ds = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
  data_dir,
  validation_split=0.2,
  subset="validation",
  seed=123,
  image_size=(img_height, img_width),
  batch_size=batch_size)

for image_batch, labels_batch in train_ds:
  print(image_batch.shape)
  print(labels_batch.shape)
  break
```

**Output:**

```
(32, 200, 600, 3)
(32,)
```